# How i can print 2 places behind the decimal point using(format bank) in script file OR where should i put it?

Tags: matlab, format

I don't know where shall i put these sentense( format bank)?

```
nominal=10000;
rangeend=43;
rangestart=41;
if(nominal>=10^3 && nominal<10^6) 
nominalz=nominal/(10^3);
ranges=rangestart/(10^3);
rangee=rangeend/(10^3);
ss=nominalz+" Kohm\n";
fprintf(ss);
ss=ranges+" Kohm to "+rangee+" Kohm\n";
fprintf(ss);
end
```

Comment: in script or in command window or in any function that you're using

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [format operator](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html#btf8xsy-1_sep_shared-formatSpec):

```
fprintf('%.2f Kohm to %.2f Kohm\n', ranges, rangee);
```

`%f` specifies a float, and `%.2f` prints a floating number with two decimals.

Comment: @AdnanAji what do you mean with (blank)?

Answer (score 0):

Change your output lines from `fprintf` to `disp`:

```
disp(ss);
```

Then you can put `format bank` anywhere before your `disp` commands. MATLAB's output to the console is affected by the `format`, but not, as you've seen, `fprintf` which has its own format specification.